# Create a cross-section, time series data set using Matrix operations

Tags: matrix, formatting

I have developed the following `code`, which produces what I aim to obtain.

```
Clear[n, t, gBar, mat0, mat1];
SeedRandom[15];
n = 5;
t = 7;
gBar = 0.05;
mat0 = Array[RandomInteger[{1, 8}] &, {n,t}]; (* Cross-section (n) over time (t) *)
mat1 = Array[0 &, {n, t - 1}];
mat2 = Array[0 &, {n, n}];
Do[
  Do[
   If[Log[mat0[[i, j + 1]]/mat0[[i, j]]] > gBar, 
    mat1[[i, j]] = Log[mat0[[i, j + 1]]/mat0[[i, j]]]], {i, 1, n}
   ], {j, 1, t - 1}
  ];

desiredOutput = ReplacePart[mat2, {{2, _} -> 1, {3, _} -> 1}]
```

First, I create a matrix of data (cross-section over time): called `mat0`. Then, for each row, I conduct a `Log[]` operation. If the outcome satisfies `If` statement, then I place the result of the operation to that row in `mat1`. Here are the resulting matrices, `mat0` and `mat1`, respectively.

[image]

After the `mat1` is fully created, then I conduct operations using each column. Find the positions of `nonzero` elements in the 1st column, for example (`mat1[2,1] and mat1[3,1]` and then create the matrix of `desiredOutput` in which `2nd` and `3rd` rows are all `one` and the rest of the matrix is `zero` as follows:

[image]

How can I make the above `code` more efficient and shorter?

**EDIT 1**

This edit does not change anything in the above formulation, but asks a related extension.

This additional `code`:

```
Clear[λ, ψ, mu, μ];
λ = 0.6;
ψ = 2;
mu = λ*(mat1[[All, 1]]/gBar)^ψ  (* the 1st column *)
μ = Table[{i, mu[[i]]}, {i, 1, n}]
```

gives me what I need. I can repeatedly calculate the code for each column in `mat1`, but it is not efficient to do so. Instead, for the integrity of my research problem, I like to incorporate this additional piece of `code` into the `code` given in the question before **EDIT 1** and automate it for each column `t` in `mat1`.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mat1` from Henrik's answer, alternative ways to get `mat2` and `mu`:

```
ClearAll[m2]
m2[m_][k_] := ArrayPad[Transpose[{Unitize[m[[All, k]]]}], 
  {0, {Dimensions[m][[1]] - 1, 0}}, "Fixed"];
Row[MatrixForm /@ m2[mat1] /@ Range[4]] // TeXForm
```

> $\tiny\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
ClearAll[mu]
mu[m_][k_] := MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, λ*(m[[All, k]]/gBar)^ψ ] ;
Row[MatrixForm /@ mu[mat1] /@ Range[6]] // TeXForm
```

> $\tiny\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 0. \\
>  2 & 39.4565 \\
>  3 & 39.4565 \\
>  4 & 0. \\
>  5 & 0. \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 0. \\
>  2 & 0. \\
>  3 & 0. \\
>  4 & 908.776 \\
>  5 & 461.235 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 230.886 \\
>  2 & 770.496 \\
>  3 & 75.1608 \\
>  4 & 0. \\
>  5 & 0. \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 0. \\
>  2 & 0. \\
>  3 & 0. \\
>  4 & 0. \\
>  5 & 115.309 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 0. \\
>  2 & 0. \\
>  3 & 0. \\
>  4 & 0. \\
>  5 & 115.309 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 39.4565 \\
>  2 & 19.8626 \\
>  3 & 0. \\
>  4 & 621.67 \\
>  5 & 0. \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Really very neat. It is just what I asked for. Thank you and Henrik.

Comment: @Tugrul, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: I think something is not right in the generation of `0` and `1` matrices. Your `m2[m_]` matrix should use columns of `mat1` to generate  6 matrices of  `(n,n)` dimension each.

Comment: Tugrul, `mat1` is `5by6` and `m2[mat1][k]` generates a 5by6 matrix based on column `k` of `mat1`. I just displayed 4 of 6 matrices because 6 wouldn't fit on the page.

Comment: Yes, I saw the 6 matrices and I understand why you did it that way. But my question is about the dimension of the `1` and `0` matrices. In the original question, the 1-0 matrix is (n,n) dimension, not (n,t-1).

Comment: hope the updated version works.

Comment: I was going to write you that `{Dimensions[m][[1]] - 1, 0}` works. But you wrote me before. Your update works fine. Thank you very much. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

- `Log` is vectorized and should not be computed more often than needed.
- `Clip` is also vectorized and can replace `If` here. This way, we also do not have to initialize the matrix `mat1`.
- `Unitize` along with `Part` can help you to generate the second matrix. Also no initialization needed.

Check this out:

```
mat1 = With[{A = Log[mat0]},
   Clip[Subtract[A[[All, 2 ;;]], A[[All, ;; -2]]], {gBar, ∞}, {0., 0.}]
   ];

mat2 = ({
     ConstantArray[0., n],
     ConstantArray[1., n]
     })[[Unitize[mat1[[All, 1]]] + 1]];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Given `mat0` and `gBar`, I run your code, but it gives me the following message: `Symbol called with 0 arguments, 1 argument is expected` and ` the expression `1+Unitize[Symbol[]] cannot be used as a part specification.` Can you tell me what the matrix `mymat1` is?

Comment: I discovered `mymat1`. It is my `mat1`. Your `code` runs perfect...

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. Fixed it. And, of course, you're welcome.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask another related question? This extra question is not worth to formulate as a separate question. Please let me know.

Comment: Yeah, okay. If it is a short one... =)

Comment: For those rows with `1`, I want to calculate `\[Lambda]*((Log[x[t + 1]] - Log[x[t]])/gBar)^\[Psi]` where `Lamda` and `Psi` are given parameters, and place the values obtained in an `Array ` i.e., `{{1, 0}, {2, 2.35}, {3, 1.6}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}}` where {i, value}={2, 2.35} for example.

Comment: I don't get it. What is `x`? And how are the rows of `mat2` related to this?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. In `mat0` given in the original question above, take for example the `(2nd row, first 2 elements)`, which are denoted as `x[t+1]=6` and `x[t]=4`. And `If` statement for this `Log[x[t+1]]-Log[x[t]]=0.405465`, which is placed in the cell `(2,1)` in `mat1`. Therefore, the `2nd row` in the `mat2` matrix is all `1`.  In my additional question, I want to create an `(n,2)` array in which `(n=2 (referring to 2nd row in `mat2`), value)` where `value=\[Lambda]*((Log[x[t + 1]] - Log[x[t]])/gBar)^\[Psi].` If my explanation is unclear, I can edit the question.

Comment: @Tugrul Yes, I'd say that editing the question is the best way to explain the details. As nobody apart from us to is involved in this thread, I think it is legitimate tomodify the question. However, I won't have time to answer before tomorrow. Good night.

Comment: I will edit the question and no hurry for this. Good night.